# PDFreactor text-decoration-color: how to colorize line-through?

Tags: css, pdf-reactor

PDFreactor does not render a line-through color other then font color.

I tried to set the color of a line-throgh.

text-decoration: line-through solid cmyk(0%, 100%, 81%, 4%);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using text-decoartion-color is (among other text-decoration CSS properties) not yet supported by PDFreactor. This as on our roadmap as feature request #7789. We plan to implement this in a future version of PDFreactor.